# How to show results based on name/category?

Tags: php, html, mysql, categories, dynamic-queries

I have a database with with these values.

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | value  | category  |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | value1 | category1 |
|  2 | value2 | category1 |
|  3 | value3 | category2 |
|  4 | value4 | category3 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

And I want the output to be like this:

```
Category1: 
value1 
value2

Category2: 
value3

Category3: 
value4
```

I know I can use `WHERE category = category1` .. etc, but how do I make the script automatically group all values and show them this way?

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT function will help produce your result for the values. You would use GROUP BY on the category column to get your result

Comment: It shows just the first value of all the categories whereas I want each values of the them!

Comment: See my answer below. As stated above, the **GROUP_CONCAT()** function will return all of the values in a comma delimited format. Google the function for more options.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function *GROUP_CONCAT()* to get a comma separated list of values, and the *GROUP BY* clause to gather the values for each category:

```
SELECT
    `category`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`value`) as `values`
FROM `tablename`
GROUP BY `category`
ORDER BY `category`
```

Comment: What is the **complete** error message? Did you substitute the correct column and table names?